# View created in SQL Server Management Studio but not visible in "Views" section

Tags: sql, view, ssms

I created a view in SQL Server Management Studio 18 and I am getting the following message:
"Commands completed successfully." which I guess means that the view has been created. However I cannot see the view in the views section of the database in the Object Explorer.

I confirmed that the view has been created by running the query again and i got an error that the object already exists.

This is the code I used to create the view:

```
    GO 
    CREATE VIEW VIEW_1 as SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations, SUM(cast(vac.new_vaccinations as INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location,dea.date) AS rolling_new_vax 
    FROM [Portfolio Project _1]..['covid vaccinations$'] vac JOIN [Portfolio Project _1]..['covid deaths$'] dea 
    ON vac.location =dea.location AND vac.date = dea.date 
    WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL AND dea.location = 'Canada'
```

Comment: Would refresh work?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the views section? You can do this by right-clicking and selecting refresh. Or by selecting the views section and clicking the refresh icon at the top of the Object Explorer.

Comment: Presumably `select * from dbo.view_1` works

Comment: thanks@Stu the select statement worked so this means the view exists. The only issue now remains to be able to see it in the object explorer. Would it have something to do with my connection? I tried refreshing but that did not work

Comment: Thanks @Freek. I tried refreshing multiple times but with no luck

Comment: If refreshing the object explorer didn't work it sounds like you didn't create the view in the database you think you did.

Comment: Might it be that you're not creating the view in the database you're expecting to?

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't the most fun answer but I had the same error on the same guided project. I saved the file then closed out of SSMS, reopened the file, deleted the Create View statement, retyped the statement, executed the query, refreshed the views folder and it worked.

Comment: So weird, but your suggestion fixed it

Answer (score 4):

On the top left corner above the object explorer there is a dropdown option of available databases, click the dropdown menu and choose your project in your case should be covid and then run the create view query, it will run.
Because your available database is set to master or some other that is why views does not show in your project views.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure the queries are done in the PortfolioProject as "UserEE" said. I suggest you begin with the USE function...
Try this:

```
USE PortfolioProject
GO
CREATE VIEW PercentPopulationVaccinated AS
Select dea.location, 
       dea.date, 
       dea.population, 
       vacc.new_vaccinations,
       SUM(CAST(vacc.new_vaccinations AS int)) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY location, dea.date) AS cummulative_people_vaccinated
FROM PortfolioProject..[CovidDeaths.Africa] dea
JOIN PortfolioProject..[CovidVaccinations.Africa] vacc
    ON dea.location = vacc.location
    AND dea.date = vacc.date
```

Comment: `USE PortfolioProject
GO`
it really helps me in another project

Answer (score 0):

if you add filter with name of your view does it show?

try this code to see the views in your DBs

```
SELECT 
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id) schema_name,o.name
FROM
sys.objects as o
WHERE
o.type = 'V';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the queries being done are for the database PortfolioProject. I created a new query file (right click PortfolioProject-> new query -> copy and paste all work done in the previous file). Execute the queries. This should create the view for the right database.

My database where I stored my files was called PortfolioProject. Add the queries based on what your database is called.